# Flawfinder error- internal buffer overflows. How to limit string input size and protect it from overflow?

Tags: c++, input, argv, getopt, flawfinder

I have the following code:

```
void parseOptions(int argc, char* argv[]) {
std::string mob;
int option, index;

    struct option long_options[] = {{"version", no_argument, 0, 'V'},
                                  {"mobile-interface", required_argument, 0, 'm'},
                                  {0, 0}};

    while ((option = getopt_long(argc, argv, "Vm:", long_options, &index)) != -1) {
      switch (option) {
        case 'V':
          printVersion();
          break;
        case 'm':
          if (strlen(optarg) == HASHED_MOB_SIZE) {
            mob = optarg;
          }
          break;
        default:
          std::cerr << "Getopt switch default case shouldn't be reached... aborting program.\n";
          exit(ERR_GETOPT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
}
```

I run `Flawfinder` and I get the following error:

> main.cpp:48:  [3] (buffer) getopt_long:
> Some older implementations do not protect against internal buffer overflows
> (CWE-120, CWE-20). Check implementation on installation, or limit the size
> of all string inputs.

How do I limit the string input size?

Comment: one option would be to use a modern c++ argument parser like `boost::program_options`

Comment: Thanks @AlanBirtles , but unfortunately I can't use boost lib in this project.

Comment: It isn't clear what buffer overflow they are talking about. `getopt_long` doesn't seem to need any writable buffers. Implementations that I can find don't appear to use any.

Comment: Thanks @n.'pronouns'm. , I don't understand it, I think I will ignore this error for now.

Comment: the solution that worked for now is to suppress the warning by adding `/* Flawfinder: ignore */` at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

So `Flawfinder` was right.

There is a Vulnerability  in `getopt`: [CVE-1999-0966](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-1999-0966/).

> Buffer overflow in Solaris getopt in libc allows local users to gain root privileges via a long argv[0].

My solution was to verify that that `argc` is greater than 1 and that `argv[0]` is not to long.